# hide scrollbar when popup transitioning

Tags: html, css, reactjs

Please look at this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7tnx4qq1/4/)** (//updated)

This is an abstraction of my app. After hiding the popup, it is being removed from DOM (with ReactCSSTransitionGroup in ReactJS).

When I'm hiding the popup, it expands `.main-content`, so an annoying scorllbar appears for a second.

The simple answer will be to add `overflow:hidden` to `.main-content`, but I don't want this.

What can I do than, to remove the popup with this slide down, but without enlarging main content

Answer (score 0):

Change the `height` of the element instead of the `margin-bottom`:

```
$('#hide').click( function() {
    $('.popup').css("height","0px")
});
$('#pop').click( function() {
    $('.popup').css("height","100px")    
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7tnx4qq1/5/)

Comment: since I have many elements inside, changing `height` looks ugly

Comment: @yonatanmn: Why? The values you use for `bottom` look like magic numbers as well. Plus, it would be no problem to _get_ the actual height of the element at runtime using jQuery as well, so it doesn’t matter how many elements that popup contains or if they might change.

Comment: forget the last comment : here is the problem - I'm using React, so I'd prefer not using jquery. and transition not working with `initial`

Comment: ok - solved it - I'm using `max-height` with estimated magic number (too big will make the animation ugly). and at the time of transition i give `.popup{overflow:hidden}`